# Multi-stage autocomplete with nodejs & redis call. How to make sure returns after everything done

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis

I am working on a auto-complete prototype.  I've looked at the several examples around the web that are auto-completes of a simple list.  My business case is multi step in the fact that the auto-complete has to handle people with same names but different year of births.

Example

User types:  Geor

Returned for possible completes:

- George 1976 - Father: George Sr.  Mother: Karen
- George 1980 - Father: Jack  Mother: Pam
- Georgiana 1972 - Father: David  Mother: Carol

So I have four steps to my redis calls:

- zrank prefix 'GEOR'

  - > 4
- zrange prefix 4 20

  - > Georg
  - > George*
  - > Georgi
  - > Georgia
  - > Georgian
  - > Georgiana*
- (for each name that ends in *)

  - smembers "compnam:GEORGE"

    - > 'personid:10'
    - > 'personid:15'
  - smembers "compnam:GEORGIANA"

    - > 'personid:53'
- (for each person)

  - hgetall 'personid:10'
  - hgetall 'personid:15'
  - hgetall 'personid:53'

Hopefully this clear enough.

I'm trying to create output similar to this:

```
 [ { name: 'George', yob: '1976', parentstr: 'Father: George Sr. Mother: Karen'},
 { name: 'George', yob: '1980', parentstr: 'Father: Jack Mother: Pam'},
 { name: 'Georgiana', yob: '1972', parentstr: 'Father: David Mother: Carol'}]
```

Here is my nodejs code.

```
var app = express();
var client = redis.createClient();

app.get('/names/:name', function(req,res) {
  var name_search = req.params.name;

  client.zrank('prefix',name_search, function (err, obj){
    client.zrange('prefix',obj+1,20, function(err,obj){
      var returnNames = [];
      async.each(obj,function(item){
        if(item.slice(item.length-1)==='*'){
          client.smembers('compnam:'+item.slice(0,item.length-1),function(err,obj){
            async.each(obj,function(item){
              client.hgetall(item,function(err,obj) {
                Array.prototype.push.call(returnNames,obj);
                console.log(returnNames);
              })
            },
            function(err) {
              console.log("error with redis1:"+err);
            });
          });
        }
      }, function(err) {
           console.log("error with redis2");
      });
      console.log("Executed here before names added");
    });
  });
});
```

I'm still very new to Node.js so I realize that I'm not structuring my code correctly for async nature of Node.js.  Any help would be appreciated.

-edit-  Sorry for the lack of clarity.  Yes, the console.log("Executed here before names are added") is executing before the rest of the work is done.  Eventually this would be changed to res.send(returnNames).  I need some help to restructure the code so that everything completes before the last console.log or if I need to put my last console.log somewhere else in a different callback.

Comment: I read your post, but nowhere do I see any questions being asked.

Comment: @thtsigma I think OP wants to make sure something happens (returns) after a bunch of asynchronous calls so I suggested using promises.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a promises, some pseudo code of [promise/A+](http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec/):

```
doSomethingAsynch().then(
  function(data){      //onfultill (when the asynch is done)
    doSometingElseAsynch();
  },
  function(error){//<--onreject this is optional
  }
 ).then(....
```

Or if you want everything in only one "try and catch"

```
doSomethingAsynch(//<--error here "Illegal input"
  function(data){
   anotherAsynchThing();//<--this one isn't called because there is an error
  } //<-- no reject method specified
 ).then(
   function(data){//<--this one not called there WAS an error, (it propagates)
   anotherAsynchThing();
  } 
 ).then(
   function(data){//<--not called
   anotherAsynchThing();
  } 
 ).then(
   function(data){<--not called
   anotherAsynchThing();
  },
  function(error){//<--this one called with error"Illegal input"
    //handle error
  }
);
```

The good thing about the above pseudo code is that if the first method would generate an error then none of the other methods would be called except the last because that has a reject method. So if the first method fails with "Illegal input" and because only the last `then` has a fail method; this method would be called with error "Illegal input". When you specify multiple reject methods they will all be called but with the same error.

Not sure what is a good promise library for node but [here](http://blog.strongloop.com/promises-in-node-js-with-q-an-alternative-to-callbacks/) is a good explanation about promises and maybe a library suggestion.